# Кости Unity 5, махи хвостом

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру где бегает собака и виляет хвостом. Есть готовая 3D моделька собаки, как сделать чтобы хвост вёл себя естественно физически? Знаю, в 3D редакторах есть такая штука как "кости", чтобы анимировать конечности. Есть ли что то подобное в Unity и можно ли это применить на уже готовую 3D модель?

Comment: [offtop]Симулятор собаки?:)[/offtop]

Comment: А почему не прописать анимацию хвосту и всё? Посидеть, расставить кадры.

Comment: Как вариант попробуй найти `DYNAMIC BONE` asset. Может поможет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку у Вас все же Unity, то мне кажется, что можно не заморачиваться анимированием собаки самому, а купить например ассет Dog - Dalmatian (за $10), и взять анимации оттуда (при условии что у вас такой же скелет), ну или если скелет не такой, то взять эту модель далматинца, переработать ее, и натянуть Ваши текстуры.